Sqlalchemy (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8) - connection timeout
I am currently trying to return the first result of this SQL command:
SELECT 
  backend.campsites.campsite_id AS backend_campsites_campsite_id, 
  backend.campsites.campground_id AS backend_campsites_campground_id, 
  backend.campsites.available_from AS backend_campsites_available_from, 
  backend.campsites.available_to AS backend_campsites_available_to, 
  backend.campsites.site_number AS backend_campsites_site_number, 
  backend.campsites.size AS backend_campsites_size, 
  backend.campsites.amenities AS backend_campsites_amenities, 
  backend.campsites.availability AS backend_campsites_availability
FROM backend.campsites
WHERE backend.campsites.size = 'Medium' 
  AND backend.campsites.campground_id = 2

But when I call this in this function I get a connection error:
def assign_campsites(Campsites):
    campsite_session = SessionLocal()
    retrieve_all_bookings = bookings.find()
    retrieve_available_campsites = campsite_session.query(Campsites).filter(Campsites.availability == True).all()
    for booking in retrieve_all_bookings:
            for campsite in retrieve_available_campsites:
                if campsite.availability == True:
                    departure_date = datetime.strptime(booking['arrival_date'], "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=7)
                    existing_booking = campsites.find_one({
                        "booking_id": booking['booking_id'],
                    })
                    if not existing_booking:
                        if booking['campsite_size'] <= campsite.size and booking['campground_id'] == campsite.campground_id:
                            # Create the MongoDB document
                            submit_mongo_doc(booking, campsite, departure_date)
                            update_campsites_table(campsite, Campsites, campsite_session)
                            
                        else:
                            current_booking = booking['campground_id']
                            current_size = campsite.size
                            assign = campsite_session.query(Campsites).filter(Campsites.size == current_size, Campsites.campground_id == current_booking).first()
                            if assign:
                                submit_mongo_doc(booking, assign, departure_date)
                                update_campsites_table(campsite, Campsites, campsite_session)
                    else:
                        continue

The error occurs because of:
assign = (
    campsite_session
        .query(Campsites)
        .filter(
            Campsites.size == current_size, 
            Campsites.campground_id == current_booking
        )
        .first()
)


Please [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback.

Please adjust title to better describe your code attempt (for future searching) and not error dump. Also, to re-echo above comment, please include full error message in body of post.
